# Induction proof on a summation with a ceiling function.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove the following for $n\ge1$

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(-1)^i=(-1)^n \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$

So I started with the Basis step for $n=1$

$\sum_{i=1}^{1} 1(-1)^1=(-1)^1 \lceil\frac{1}{2}\rceil$
$-1=-1$

which is true.

Then, I got stuck on the induction step, unsure how to proceed. Here's what I got so far though:

Let $k\ge1$. We must show that if $\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(-1)^i=(-1)^k \lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(-1)^i=(-1)^{k+1} \lceil\frac{k+1}{2}\rceil$.

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(-1)^i=(-1)^k \lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil$ is true.

Observe that

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(-1)^i=(\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(-1)^i)+(k+1)(-1)^{k+1}$
$............=(-1)^k \lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil+(k+1)(-1)^{k+1}$
$............=?$ unsure how to simplify from here

Comment: Factor out $(-1)^{k+1}$ and work with he expression that remains.

Comment: If the ceiling function is giving you so much trouble, then considering running two separate induction proofs., one for even values of $n$ and one for odd values of $n$ so that you can remove the ceiling function entirely from the statement.